# I'm looking for a word opposite to dying

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

When something is dying it is not completely dead. Only half or almost there. I need a word that means gaining life, as in almost completely alive. Like the reverse of dying. When you die the flame of life dims and burns out. I'm looking for a dim light that increases its intensity as fuel is added. I can think of perfectly good antonyms like *waning*, *dimming*, *dwindle*, *ebbing*, *fading*, but not many synonyms. It doesn't sound right.

It's a weird description, but it doesn't have to necessarily be about life. Maybe light, or fire or anything. Does such a word exist? If not, is there any word or several words that sound like this?

Comment: Do you mean something like *revive, revivify, be resuscitated, quicken, reanimate, be energized, be resurrected?*

Comment: Have you looked for antonyms of *wane, dim, dwindle, ebb, fade*?

Comment: @Brenda - I would go with Erik. A weird problem needs a weird solution. Use resurrected. This will convey what you want to convey, and will also exaggerate the meaning a little bit - which will be in your favor, of course.

Comment: English doesn't have an active verb for being born. _Born_ itself is deponent and must appear in the passive. Other than that, _being born_ the opposite of _dying_, at least for mammals. Birds, etc. might substitute _hatching_. All the other words suggested are for bringing live things back to life, rather than beginning life (as death is ending it).

Comment: _Born_ used to be the past participle of _bear_ but it's been specialized for this usage, and a homonym with a different spelling (_borne_) is now considered the pple of _bear_. I.e, "I could never have borne/*born the embarrassment."

Comment: You may of course believe anything you like, but _be born_ is an intransitive stative predicate with no corresponding active intransitive predicate. If you think it ought to be called an "adjective", after due consideration and analysis, it's your language, after all. But believing POS listings in online dictionaries is a pretty useless game; they're free, and they're worth what they cost.

Comment: Actually, if you're going to dismiss references as POS, then I'm simply not willing to continue this conversation. I've removed my earlier comments, and encourage you to do the same for the comments that are no longer relevant.

Comment: I vote for vitalize or vivify. Or maybe enliven?

Comment: If he is not dying, he is alive, exuberant and thriving.

Comment: If the word isn't resurrecting than I am badly mistaken in reading the question. (Oh look it's even my spell check).

Comment: Perhaps healing since it also is a transient state..

Comment: Seeing how we now have 20 answers that are all over the map (adjectives, transitive verbs, intransitive verbs, complete phrases, me-toos, and even utter nonsense), I have to put this on hold as unclear, pending further clarification by the OP. Please specify at least the part of speech and register you are after. If you can also provide some context or a sample sentence, even better. And if there are some words you've specifically considered but rejected, please do list them as well. Thanks.

Comment: Since my answer will probably never get noticed down at the bottom of this stack, I would like to reiterate that I believe the word you were looking for was 'quickening'. Wiktionary defines this as 'The action of bringing someone or something to life.' When something is in the process of quickening it is neither fully alive nor fully dead but somewhere in between. If used in the context of starting a fire this word refers to the period after the fire has been kindled but before the blaze has reached full intensity. e.g. "While the fire was quickening she set about dicing the bacon."

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps the word **rejuvenating**.

This refers to something or someone gaining strength or vigour it once/previously had.

Comment: Irrelevant fun fact: Directly translating the root and stem from the Latin from whence they came, this means "being made young again". Since as you get older, you die, it has a nice symmetry -- you're made young again as the opposite of that.

Comment: Yeah - that's really appropriate!

Answer (score 17):

A living thing would **revitalize**.

> [revitalize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revitalize) (v): to make (someone or something) active, healthy, or energetic again; to give new life or vigor to.

A light would **brighten** or **intensify**.

Comment: I was going to suggest "brighten (up)" also. I think it can be used in different contexts also if we include the figurative sense.

Answer (score 8):

A person would be *recovering*. A light would be *intensifying*. A houseplant would be *perking-up*.

Comment: Recovering sounds too dull and in slow motion. Doesn't it?

Comment: Not if the person has been in a coma for five years.  ("My God, Madge, get your new husband out of the room... Fred is recovering!")

Comment: Well, in that case, I agree with you. I am just pointing out the sheer drag that comes with the word recovery. Recovery doesn't show immediacy, I think.

Answer (score 7):

‘[regenerating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regeneration_%28biology%29)’ or perhaps ‘[reviving](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revive)’

It's often used in sci-fi for example Dr.Who *regenerates*

This is really context dependent.

Who comes back to life? Why? How should we feel about it?
Was he dead or just injured? Was this a physical or brain injury? Is the healing magical, mechanical or by providence?

Comment: Could you please flesh out your answer. Perhaps provide examples, or references etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a word like *kindling*, which means to arouse or inspire, to start building a fire. It is the opposite of dying.

Comment: Or indeed *rekindling*.

Comment: You picked the wrong definitions. With those definitions, the opposite of dying would not be kindling, it would be being kindled. But kindle can also be used as an intransitive verb, and in that sense, it's a good fit.

Comment: You've got your grammar slightly off -- kindling is a noun. The verb is 'to kindle'.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes …and its gerund form is *kindling* as well.

Comment: @WChagrin ...Oh right! Though the way he uses it later ('**to** arouse or inspire, **to** start building a fire') suggests that he should use 'to kindle'.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest **nascent**.

It means "coming into being" or "beginning to develop, or grow", and is derived from the Latin *nasci* meaning "to be born".

Answer (score 3):

The word you're looking for is **thriving**

verb
gerund or present participle: thriving
(of a child, animal, or plant) grow or develop well or vigorously.
"the new baby thrived"
prosper; flourish.

Comment: I take thriving to be more like "starting well, staying well, and growing from there."

Answer (score 3):

Something could ***enliven*** or ***(re-)vitalize***, or become ***invigorated*** or undergo ***excitation*** or even ***essentiation***?

Answer (score 3):

The word **[waxing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waxing)** is close to your stated requirements.

> > intransitive verb
>
> 1   a :  to increase in size, numbers, strength, prosperity, or
>   intensity
>     b :  to grow in volume or duration
>    c :  to grow
>   toward full development
>
> 2 :  to increase in phase or intensity —used chiefly of the moon,
>   other satellites, and inferior planets

It's not all that common a word on its own- more often seen in partnership with **waning** as in [this](http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2015/03/economic-backgrounder) headline from **The Economist**.

Comment: I was going to say waxing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the stirring of a new life, or the rebirth of a previous one? In the first case, perhaps "dawning" might do: increasing brightness and a new beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Not a single-word but a victorious simile

### rise like a phoenix from the ashes

> Emerge renewed after apparent disaster or destruction:
>   *the team began their brave attempt to rise like some [phoenix](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/phoenix) from the ashes*
>
> <sup>Oxford Dictionaries</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I thought for sure the cancer would take Don, but now he's **rallying**.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the word you're looking for is **quickening**.

Wiktionary defines this as 'The action of bringing someone or something to life.' When something is in the process of quickening it is neither fully alive nor fully dead but somewhere in between. If used in the context of starting a fire this word refers to the period after the fire has been kindled but before the blaze has reached full intensity. e.g. "While the fire was quickening she set about dicing the bacon."